# Not receiving emails from addresses with a specific @ending

Tags: email, email-filter, windows-live-mail, outlook.com

Title. I have a @live.com address.

I've checked my Outlook "rules," and none of them should be deleting emails from @blank addresses.

The sender has confirmed that the emails were "sent" on their end. They claim to not know why the emails have not been received.

I have checked Junk Mail.

I have seen an email from a @blank address successfully sent to someone else, and saw my email address listed as a CC. However I did not receive this CC.

I have tried disabling all of my rules in the unlikely case that they are deleting emails from @blank addresses, but am still waiting for a test email to be sent from a @blank address.

Could live mail/Outlook.com have any way of filtering emails besides the "rule" menu? Could it be something on the sender's end that they are unaware of?

Comment: Can you get to them on live.com?

Comment: I have checked live.com/outlook.com and have not found the emails. I have checked the "rules" menu on outlook.com.

Answer (score 2):

Sender mail server IP could be blacklisted, and outlook.com could be dropping their mails due to that.

Go to http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx and type the problematic domain there, to see if their MX record IP is blacklisted.

Also, if possible sender should check mail logs on his SMTP server, or ask his email provider to check it.

His SMTP server IP could be blocked on Microsoft, and in that case will probably return one of this SMTP codes to his SMTP server.

---

SMTP Error Codes

421 RP-001  The mail server IP connecting to Outlook.com server has exceeded the rate limit allowed. Reason for rate limitation is related to IP/domain reputation. If you are not an email/network admin please contact your Email/Internet Service Provider for help.

421 RP-002  The mail server IP connecting to Outlook.com server has exceeded the rate limit allowed on this connection. Reason for rate limitation is related to IP/domain reputation. If you are not an email/network admin please contact your Email/Internet Service Provider for help.

421 RP-003  The mail server IP connecting to Outlook.com server has exceeded the connection limit allowed. Reason for limitation is related to IP/domain reputation. If you are not an email/network admin please contact your Email/Internet Service Provider for help.

550 SC-001  Mail rejected by Outlook.com for policy reasons. Reasons for rejection may be related to content with spam-like characteristics or IP/domain reputation. If you are not an email/network admin please contact your Email/Internet Service Provider for help.

550 SC-002  Mail rejected by Outlook.com for policy reasons. The mail server IP connecting to Outlook.com has exhibited namespace mining behavior. If you are not an email/network admin please contact your Email/Internet Service Provider for help.

550 SC-003  Mail rejected by Outlook.com for policy reasons. Your IP address appears to be an open proxy/relay. If you are not an email/network admin please contact your Email/Internet Service Provider for help.

550 SC-004  Mail rejected by Outlook.com for policy reasons. A block has been placed against your IP address because we have received complaints concerning mail coming from that IP address. We recommend enrolling in our Junk Email Reporting Program (JMRP), a free program intended to help senders remove unwanted recipients from their email list. If you are not an email/network admin please contact your Email/Internet Service Provider for help.

550 DY-001  Mail rejected by Outlook.com for policy reasons. We generally do not accept email from dynamic IP's as they are not typically used to deliver unauthenticated SMTP email to an Internet mail server. If you are not an email/network admin please contact your Email/Internet Service Provider for help. http://www.spamhaus.org maintains lists of dynamic and residential IP addresses.

550 DY-002  Mail rejected by Outlook.com for policy reasons. The likely cause is a compromised or virus infected server/personal computer. If you are not an email/network admin please contact your Email/Internet Service Provider for help.

550 OU-001  Mail rejected by Outlook.com for policy reasons. If you are not an email/network admin please contact your Email/Internet Service Provider for help. For more information about this block and to request removal please go to: http://www.spamhaus.org.

550 OU-002  Mail rejected by Outlook.com for policy reasons. Reasons for rejection may be related to content with spam-like characteristics or IP/domain reputation. If you are not an email/network admin please contact your Email/Internet Service Provider for help.

---

Check this link for more troubleshooting options.
https://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx

Sometimes when sender IP is blocked, Microsoft servers will return bounce back mail to sender, but in some case there will be no bounce back, and only thing to see that IP is blocked will be SMTP error code in mail logs on sender side.

Whether or not their mail IP is whitelisted, sender should check with his mail provider, or administrator of SMTP server, and have them check mail logs, to see if Microsoft servers are returning the 250 OK code, or some other code, indicating some problems, when mail is handed over to their SMTP servers.

Comment: The domain is listed 0 times. 
It is unlikely that the email would be blocked by Microsoft for policy reasons as the sender is a big business. They would have this issue with many others.

Comment: Did their mail server admin, or mail provider check their mail logs? First thing to troubleshoot this would be to check what SMTP reply code are Microsoft servers returning when mail is being handed over to them, it could be connection issues, or their server having sending errors of some sort. Also big business doesn't mean they won't be blacklisted, I have seen Yahoo.com getting their mail servers blacklisted many times.